# Play Framework 1.2.5 Excel Module Can't Parse Cell tag jx:forEach

Tags: excel, playframework-1.x, jxls

Hi the following is my java method

```
public static void csvReport(String date) throws Exception
{
    request.format = "xlsx";
    renderArgs.put(RenderExcel.RA_ASYNC, true);
    renderArgs.put("results", currentResults.values());
    renderArgs.put("date", date);
    render();
}
```

Then My view looks like

```
<jx:forEach items="${results}" var="result">                    
${result.simpleName}    ${result.version}   ${result.registerCount} ${result.uniqueAccess}  ${result.totalAccess}   ${result.updateCount}
</jx:forEach>
```

But when I run this, I get a `NullPointerException` due to a parse failure at `item` attribute which says **Open quote at the attribute.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: I had a similar problem with jxls.
For some reason, the character " (open quote) in OpenOffice doesn't fit with jxls.
I simply changing it for 'the same character' from a text editor (copy&paste)